# Set min/max axis with date

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I have to show a line graph with the date in the X axis.
I use the following method for show correctly the dates:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getApplicationContext()));
```

But I have a problem: I can't set the min and the max value of axis with the date because the methods setMinX and setMaxX accept the only double value, not date.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should add a bit more information. *graph* seems to be an object, but of which Class?

Comment: graph is a GraphView object